# Get channel ID after cloning DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a DiscordJS bot, and I want to move my user to the a channel I cloned. For this I need to get the ID of the channel, and I don't know how to do that.

```
bot.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannelID = newMember.voiceChannelID
  let newUserName = newMember.username
  let channel = bot.channels.get("626043862397354025")

  if(newUserChannelID == "534437314231926804") {
    channel.clone('Salon privé de ' + newUserName, true, false, 'Création channel privé.')
    .then(clone => console.log(`Clone du channel ${channel.name} pour faire un nouveau channel nommé ${clone.name}`))
    .catch(console.error);

    let newPrivateChannel = clone.voiceChannelID

    newMember.setVoiceChannel(newPrivateChannel)
  }
});
```

The clone method is returning a GuildChannel object.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: ... let newPrivateChannel = clone <- undefined - scope it into then(...)

Comment: I'm trying that, thank you !

Comment: @Estradiaz I looked for it but I don't know how to scope it, i'm new in javascript...

Comment: try to understand this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions and compare this with his line `.then(clone => console.log(`Clone du ...` - also check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope - if still something is unclear just ask ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz Like that ? `if(newUserChannelID == "534437314231926804") {
    channel.clone('Salon privé de ' + newUserName, true, false, 'Création channel privé.')
    .then(clone => this.newPrivateChannel = clone.id)
    .catch(console.error);

    newMember.setVoiceChannel(newPrivateChannel)
  }` I don't really know where is my error lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more like this:

```
if(newUserChannelID == "534437314231926804") {
    channel.clone('Salon privé de ' + newUserName, true, false, 'Création channel privé.')
    .then(clone => {
               console.log(`Clone du channel ${channel.name} pour faire un nouveau channel nommé ${clone.name}`)
               // clone is available
               let newPrivateChannel = clone.voiceChannelID

               newMember.setVoiceChannel(newPrivateChannel)
    })
    .catch(console.error);

  }
```

Comment: forgot to thank you lol, it's now working, thanks for your help. I'm looking for a way to delete the channel if the user leaves it now!